# isolate source of error

Tags: errors

What is the best way to find the source of error `Paragraph ended before \underline was complete.`? As far as I know this could be any missing parentheses whatsoever. I got several files for text that I merge in a main file. I tried to isolate the source of error by commenting out each file one by one but the error persists, what I don't understand to be honest.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi dude, have a closer look at your log file, it probably tells you a line number and the file it is processing right now. Maybe the error is in an auxiliary file. [A simple algorithm](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) helps you to find the cause.

Comment: Keep doing what you've already started: Remove bit by bit until you're left with the smallest piece of code that reproduces the error. Essentially the process of creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=83727#83727)

Comment: The log file tells you which file and what line the error is on.

Comment: If you run latex with the `-file-line-error` option, it will show the filename and line number at the start of the error message.

Answer (score 1):

`Paragraph ended before \underline was complete.`: You want to underline something but the argument of `\underline{...}` has an empty line, which is the end of a paragraph. But `\underline` works only inside *one* paragraph. In most cases one has forgotten the corresponding closing `}`